# vue-cli project source map not working/how to get working

Tags: vue-cli, source-maps

I created a new project using vue-cli(`@vue/cli 4.3.1`). When there is an error in one of my component files(.vue file), in chrome console i do not see the actual file/line number. Instead i see a file reference called `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619`. Did some googling on how to enable source map. I added a `vue.config.js` file on my project root and added below lines:

```
module.exports = {
   configureWebpack: (config) => {
       config.devtool = 'eval-source-map'
   },
   productionSourceMap: true
};
```

Did `npm run server`. But still i do not see the actual file reference.

How do i enable source map in a vue-cli-project??

```
\\File: packages.json
{
  "name": "real-world-vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "build-watch": "vue-cli-service build-watch --mode development"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "json-server": "^0.16.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
    "vuex": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-build-watch": "~1.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}

Please help.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got it to work using `devtool` right under `configureWebpack`, so no `config` field there.

I also had to use `'cheap-module-source-map'` instead of `'eval-source-map'`. In the end it would look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  },
   productionSourceMap: true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the chrome console in advance, add "debugger" in file, and then ("command" + "s") save the file which to be debugged, follow these steps, it will works.